# Is there a way to have multiple columns in a QMenu?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qmenu

Is there a way to have multiple columns in a QMenu? I'm using Qt with C++. I have searched and there does not seem to be a way to do this built in to Qt. The question then is how do I add this functionality to my program? Has anyone built a custom menu that can have multiple columns?

Comment: How do you mean, multiple columns? Please elaborate and I think I may be able to help you.

Comment: @Rob I have a pop-up menu that is displayed when a button is clicked. I would like to have two columns in this menu instead of just one. It should look something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YMSJd.png

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back, Ive been very busy but that is an interesting question. I have done a little research and I dont think you can out of the box without modifying anything, but im still looking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a submenu is what you're looking for. As qt doc [says](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qmenu.html#details):

> Separators are inserted with addSeparator(), submenus with addMenu(), and all other items are considered action items.

For example, here there is a full example. And "Format" menu item is a submenu. You can add a submenu with:

```
m_mysubmenu = QMenu(...);
...
m_menu->addMenu(m_mysubmenu);
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats not quit what I'm looking for.